# Mostrar e esconder menu toggle. A função mostrar não funciona. Podem me ajudar?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!-- header -->
   <header class="header header-fixheight header--fixed">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="header__inner">
      <div class="header-logo"><a href="home.html"><img src="assets/img/logo-menu.png" alt=""/></a></div>
      
      <!-- raising-nav -->
      <nav class="raising-nav">
       
       <!-- raising-menu -->
       <ul class="raising-menu" id="menu-1">
        <li class="current"><a class="nav-link" href="#id1">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#id2">Sobre Nós</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#id3">Serviços</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#id4">Galeria</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#id5">Depoimentos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#id6">Sobre</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#id7">Contato</a>
        </li>
       </ul><!-- raising-menu -->
       
       <div class="navbar-toggle" id="hamburguer"><i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="mostrarmenu()"></i></div>

      </nav><!-- Fim / raising-nav -->
     </div>
    </div>
   </header><!-- Fim / header -->
```

NO código abaixo, a função esconde direitinho, mas não funciona para mostrar.
Podem me ajudar a resolver?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".nav-link").click(function(){
          $("#menu-1").toggle('hide');
       });
     });

     function mostrarmenu(){
         $("#menu-1").toggle('show'); 
         }
</script>
```

Comment: Edita ai sua pergunta e coloca o html vai facilitar pra te responder

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você deve ter feito algum tipo de confusão, o método jQuery [toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) alterna a visibilidade dos elementos por si só, não precisa passar parâmetros de **hide** ou **show**:

```js
$("#menu-1").hide();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-link").click(function() {
    $("#menu-1").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="nav-link">Mostrar/Esconder</button>

<ul id="menu-1">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Como eu disse,
Só fecha com o código acima, mas depois que fecha não abre de novo.
O menu começa a aparecer e esconde de novo

Comment: Com o código que vc postou o que esperava que acontecesse? O único resultado é o que vc falou mesmo, quando vc clica nos links vc esconde eles, de que forma iria conseguir abri-los de novo?